# Did 'the' in 'the which' mean anything?

Tags: english, etymology, lexical-semantics

I was advised to repost my [original ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311577/did-the-in-the-which-mean-anything#comment735714_311577) here.

1. Did 'the' mean anything in **the which**, compared with the relative pronoun **which**? OED's entries for [**the which**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/228284?redirectedFrom=the+which#eid14745204) only redirect to definitions of 'which'.

I am unsure because cognates of **the which** remain in Romance languages and do  differ from 'which'. For instance, 'que' differs from: (all in one word in French) « le(s)/la + quel(le)(s)», and (as two words in Spanish)  « el/lo/los/la/las/lo + que ».

The latter two are really cognates by Grimm's Law; the 'q' in Latin (phoneme [kʷ]) turned into 't' in Germanic languages like English (phoneme [xʷ]).

2. What factors or reasons might have caused  'the which' to vanish?

Comment: _The which_ is simply an alternate construction of the relative pronoun _which_ (probably only introducing nonrestrictive relative clauses). The construction has fallen out of habit, and appears now only in old writing, or in new writing that's trying to sound old. That's all.

Comment: @jlawler Wish you to answer this question with that comment (per http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1688/5306)? If not, I can await further answers.

Comment: @Le: Yes, under the circumstances, I will. Thanks.

Comment: *'t' in Germanic languages* should read *wh* (or *w*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The which* is simply an alternate construction of the relative pronoun *which* (probably only introducing nonrestrictive relative clauses).

> *the which*: (archaic) a longer form of *which*, often used as a sentence connector
> Source: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-which

The construction has fallen out of habit -- Harper Collins marks it "(archaic)" -- and it appears now only in old writing, or in new writing that's trying to sound old. The reason why *the* in *the which* fell out of favor is probably because *the* there adds nothing to the sentence but a certain fustian elegance. Non-restrictive relative clauses are already presupposed, hence definite; nothing is served by adding a definite article.

As noted in the question, Latin *qui, quae, quod, quis, quid,* and all their descendants still spelled with *qu* in Romance languages are historically cognate with *what, why, which,* etc. via Grimm's Law. Where Romance languages have *qu*-words in their grammars, English has *wh*-words.

More interestingly, also via Grimm's Law, where Latin  had demonstrative *t*-words like *tantum* and *talis* matching interrogative *qu*-words like like *quantum* and *qualis*, English has demonstrative *th*-words like *that, then, there, thither, thence* matching interrogative *what, when, where, whither, whence*. Just as PIE labiovelar **kʷ* became labiovelar stop *qu*- (originally pronounced [kʷ]) in Latin (and most other IE languages)  and labiovelar fricative *wh*- originally pronounced [xʷ]) in English (and other Germanic languages), PIE dental **t* became dental stop *t*- in Latin and dental fricative *th*- in English. Those are two of the 12 systematic consonant changes that make up Grimm's Law.